# Firebase not reporting crash to the console

Tags: android, firebase, crash

I am using firebase in android application.
Suddenly after few days firebase stopped reporting crashes to main firebase console.
I am getting following error whenever any crash occurs in app.

```
FirebaseCrash: Error sending crash report
                                                               bkz: Server did not receive report: Origin Error message: API key expired. Please renew the API key.
                                                                   at blj.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:1053)
                                                                   at blp.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:5055)
                                                                   at blp.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:54)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My gradle file is like below

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
```

I have tried renewing api key but i didnt get anyway to renew it .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **console of Firebase**, *settings*, *project configuration*, *download* `google-services.json` and drop in to your project. Rebuild and let me know if I have helped you , good programming!

Comment: You are awesome man. It got fixe in debug . I ll check in release and update here. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: No problem and greetings! This is what happens when be delete and be create new app in firebase... xD